# Произведение двух чисел

Tags: javascript

В примере с суммой

```
0.1 + 0.2
```

решается

```
(0.1*10 + 0.2*10)/10 = 0.3
```

Как быть с `0.1 * 0.2 = 0.020000000000000004`
Вариант с toFixed(n) не подойдет, т.к точность всегда нужна разная, в зависимости от перемножаемых значений

Comment: не знаю зачем и почему это вам нужно, попробуйте по аналогии `(0.1*10*0.2*10)/100`

Answer (score 4):

Для чисел с плавающей запятой другая арифметика. Связано с тем, что если число однозначно не раскладывается на слагаемые, которые являются степенями двойки, то будет возникать "хвост" цифр после запятой.
http://vestikinc.narod.ru/AB/ni_bin.htm

Результат вычисления для чисел с плавающей запятой нельзя сравнивать ни через == ни через ===, потому что этот хвостик может слегка отличаться. При сравнении используется округление до нужной степени точности.

не так: 0.1 + 0.2 ~= 0.3   (приблизительно равно)
а вот так: abs((0.1 + 0.2) - 0.3) < 0.0001 ,  где 0.0001 - требуемая точность

---

Один из вариантов вычисления точности результата арифметических операций:

Пусть имеем два числа с плавающей запятой **A** и **B**. У числа А есть **M** цифр после запятой, а у B есть **K** цифр после запятой.

Нужно выполнить 4 операции: сложение, вычисление, деление, умножение.

**При вычитании и сложении** количество цифр после запятой равно **максимуму** из M и K:

*Пример: число А = 0.111, количество цифр после запятой M = 3; B = 0.0001, количество цифр K = 4; количество цифр после запятой в результате = max(M;K) = max(3;4) = 4*

*Получается, что результат должен быть с 4 цифрами после запятой, а именно 0.111 + 0.0001 = 0.1111*

**При умножении** А на B количество цифр после запятой равно **сумме** M и K.

*Пример: число А = 0.111, количество цифр после запятой M = 3; B = 0.0001, количество цифр K = 4; количество цифр после запятой в результате = M + K = 3 + 4 = 7*

*0.111 * 0.0001 = 0.0000111 при округлении до 7 знака после запятой*

**При делении** А на B количество цифр после запятой равно **разности** M и K. Если результат получился отрицательный, значит число получается целое, без дробной части

*Пример: число А = 0.111, количество цифр после запятой M = 3; B = 0.0001, количество цифр K = 4; количество цифр после запятой в результате = M - K = 3 - 4 = -1*

*0.111 / 0.0001 = 1110 (округление до целых)*

*Пример: число А = 0.1111, количество цифр после запятой M = 4; B = 0.11, количество цифр K = 2; количество цифр после запятой в результате = M - K = 4 - 2 = 2*

*0.1111 / 0.11 = 1.01 (округление до 2х цифр после запятой)*

С простой арифметикой разобрались ?

Для простоты всегда можно брать количество цифр после запятой в результате как как произведение M * K (корни, степени, логарифмы, тригонометрия), но из-за особенностей преобразования в двоичные числа всё равно может появиться "хвостик" незначащих цифр.

---

И эти положения про арифметику вообще никак не согласуются с тем, как результат будет сохранён в базе данных, передан по сети (в двоичном виде) и обработан получателем и много других аспектов. Это только про арифметику для реализации калькулятора.

Comment: мне нужно получить такой же результат как на калькуляторе для всех чисел, которые нельзя разложить в двоичной системе.  
Имел я ввиду то, что для сложения таких чисел есть решение или хак, как быть с произведением, когда нужна разная степень точности в зависимости от перемножаемых чисел. Вопрос открытый

Comment: @ruslik, по какому критерию определяется, что вот те четыре многонулевых - это ненужная часть, которая входит в допустимую погрешность?

Comment: По какому критерию определяет Google калькулятор, что 0.1 * 0.2 = 0.02 ?
А 0.4 * 0.4 = 0.16, а не 0.16000000000000003

Comment: дополнил свой ответ примерами вычисления точности для калькулятора

Comment: Ваши размышление конечно хороши, но...

> При вычитании и сложении количество цифр после запятой равно максимуму из M и K:

ага, конечно - `0.00001 + 0.99999`

пять цифр после запятой? С вычитанием все ещё проще. Там такие примеры сходу сочиняются.

> При умножении А на B количество цифр после запятой равно сумме M и K.

Например `0.2*0.5` ... Ага, в компании с конечным нулем.

> При делении А на B количество цифр после запятой равно разности M и K. Если результат получился отрицательный, значит число получается целое, без дробной части

`0.1 / 0.03 = 3.333333...` - ага, целое, без дробной.

Comment: >>> `- 0.00001 + 0.99999`
0.99998 не вижу проблемы

>>> Ага, в компании с конечным нулем
не вижу проблемы, незначащие нулевые разряды на точность не влияют

>>> 0.1 / 0.03 = 3.333333
Да, вы правы - http://take.ms/w1z7l . Пусть я ошибся. Возьмите для деления формулу: количество цифр после запятой = сумме M + K. 
А что даёт калькулятор в windows? Он считает с определённой точностью, в данном случае - 16 цифр после запятой. Исходников калькулятора у меня нет, проверить не могу.

Comment: В BigNumber при делении количество цифр после запятой в результате берётся как max(M;K)

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev Вы перекрутили мой пример. В `0.00001 + 0.99999` минуса нет. Там сложение. А то, что Вы приняли за минус - это тире.

> А что даёт калькулятор в windows?

У нас обсуждение javascript/google-калькулятора. Да и винда не у всех есть.

> не вижу проблемы, незначащие нулевые разряды на точность не влияют

А автору вопроса как раз хочется "человеческий результат". Кстати, гугл калькулятор все нули в конце отбросит.

А BigNumber можно и написать свой, "правильный".

Comment: @ruslik, восхитительный ответ. Предлагаю вам решение согласно ему: тяните курлом гугл-калькулятор.

Comment: @ruslik



> По какому критерию определяет Google калькулятор, что

> 0.1 * 0.2 = 0.02

> А 0.4 * 0.4 = 0.16, а не 0.16000000000000003

по тому же критерию, по которому 0.16000000000000003 +1 = 1.16 в гуглокалькуляторе (округляем по какой-то знак, не знаю точно по какой)

Comment: в общем ваш вариант такой (чтобы было почти как в гугле, правда справа - 16 знаков значащих):

    parseFloat((1/10+2/10).toPrecision(16)) //0.3


(для справки в гугле **1000000000000001-1000000000000000=0**)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно "нормальное поведение" (я специально взял в кавычки), то нужно написать (или взять чужую готовую) библиотеку для длинной арифметики. Такую библиотеку написать на самом деле не очень сложно и для разминки мозгов самое оно. Само число можно представить в виде строки (да, строки) или массива цифр + порядок. Сложение/вычитание делается легко, с умножением чуточку сложнее (придется вспомнить, что такое умножение в столбик). Потом деление и корень квадратный. Все остальное будет просто.

Для javascript есть [BigNumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber).